# Skeletal Joint smoothing in zigfu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I am using zigfu in Unity3d and animating a model using the kinect.

I am getting the position value and rotation value with the joint id, using the zigfu which i am passing to the model and animatin it.

```
if (joint.GoodPosition)
      UpdatePosition(joint.Id, joint.Position);



if (joint.GoodRotation) 
      UpdateRotation(joint.Id, joint.Rotation);
```

But I am getting too much jitter. I googled out, and found about the double exponential filter which the microsoft sdk uses .

so

1.It will be great if someone explains the basic idea on how to apply the filter over those parameters .

1. Should i filter both the position and rotation value of the joint or any one.Which will be better.